# Using the color picker in a styled component gives really long HSL values

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, color-picker

I started using React and Styled Components to build a new app and am running into a weird issue with HSL colors. When I try to use the color picker to pick a color in HSL it gives really long values like 'hsl(128.4375, 28.82882882882883%, 43.529411764705884%)'. This seems to only happen styled components, in normal CSS files it clamps the values to whole percents and degrees. This wasn't happening in my last project I worked on a few months ago, but now when I go back to it, it's also happening there.

Anyone ever have something similar happen and know how to get the Styled Components to clamp the values back to whole percents when using the color picker? I'm guessing it might be an extension. Going to try disabling them one by one and seeing what happens.